# Create array from a list generated by grep

Tags: bash

I have a list of threads stored in a file. I can retrieve the threads name with a grep:

```
$ grep "#" stack.out
"MSC service thread 1-8" #20 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f473c045800 nid=0x7f8 waiting on condition [0x00007f4795216000]
"MSC service thread 1-7" #19 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4740001000 nid=0x7f7 waiting on condition [0x00007f479531b000]
"MSC service thread 1-6" #18 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f4738001000 nid=0x7f4 waiting on condition [0x00007f479541c000]
. . .
```

As I'd need to manipulate the output of this list, I'd need to store these lines in an Array.
I've found some examples suggesting this approach:

```
$ export my_array=( $(grep "#" stack.out) )
```

However if I browse through the Array I don't get the same result from my earlier grep:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"

"MSC
service
thread
1-8"
#20
prio=5
os_prio=0
tid=0x00007f473c045800
nid=0x7f8
waiting
on
condition
[0x00007f4795216000]
"MSC
service
thread
1-7"
#19
prio=5
os_prio=0
tid=0x00007f4740001000
nid=0x7f7
waiting
on
condition
[0x00007f479531b000]
```

It seems that carriage returns are messing with my array assignment.
Any help how to fix it ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an *antipattern* to populate an array! moreover, the `export` keyword is very likely wrong. Use a loop or `mapfile` instead:

With a loop:

```
my_array=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
    my_array+=( "$line" )
done < <(grep "#" stack.out)
```

or with `mapfile` (with Bash≥4):

```
mapfile -t my_array < <(grep "#" stack.out)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Both replies were correct: I've chosen this one as you provided an additional way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the output of grep is being split on *all* whitespace before the array is created, so every word becomes a separate element in the array.

Use `mapfile` to create your array instead:

```
mapfile -t my_array < <(grep "#" stack.out)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation